# Adding an Advertisment Banner on a Package Plan

Tags: html, css

I have seen this done on other sites and i was wonding if there was a way to add it to my site without having an external image with only using HTML and CSS. So what it is is on my site i have "cards" on my page and in those cards where are packages that in each card and some plans are better than other and i want to display. Something like this in the top right corner of the card
http://cliparts101.com/files/10/370381D4E69D42D621F694F53A4E045D/Banner_137.png
and it has the text "best value" Or something like that. Would i have to do this with an image and just overlay text or is there a way to do it with css

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="cardTitle">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Basic Plan</h1>
                </div>
                <hr class="cardRuler">
                <div class="cardBody">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Lorem</li>
                        <li>Lorem</li>
                        <li>Lorem</li>
                        <li>Lorem</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="cardFooter">
                    <button class="btn button-Primary center-block">Learn More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a ribbon such as this using :before and :after pseudoelements on the container in pure CSS.

```css
.ribbon {
 font-size: 16px !important;
 width: 50%;
 position: relative;
 background: #ba89b6;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1em 2em; 
 margin: 2em auto 3em;
}
.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 bottom: -1em;
 border: 1.5em solid #986794;
 z-index: -1;
}
.ribbon:before {
 left: -2em;
 border-right-width: 1.5em;
 border-left-color: transparent;
}
.ribbon:after {
 right: -2em;
 border-left-width: 1.5em;
 border-right-color: transparent;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before, .ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #804f7c transparent transparent transparent;
 bottom: -1em;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before {
 left: 0;
 border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
.ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
 right: 0;
 border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon">
   <strong class="ribbon-content">Random Content</strong>
</div>
```